# How to convert Roman numerals into decimal numbers?

Tags: oracle, plsql

This converts a decimal number into Roman numerals:

```
select  to_char(515, 'RN') from dual;
```

Returns: `DXV`

How to do the reverse? This throws `ORA-01722: Invalid number`:

```
select to_number('DXV', 'RN') from dual;
```

Comment: Inglese, per favore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for fun, an alternative that splits the string into the groups of single and adjacent numerals, allowing for standard subtractive notation (thank you, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals); converts each single or adjacent pairs or numerals into their decimal equivalents; and then sums them:

```
with t (str) as (select 'MCMLXXXIV' from dual)
select sum(
  case regexp_substr(str, '(CM|M|CD|D|XC|C|XL|L|IX|X|IV|V|I)', 1, level)
    when 'M'  then 1000
    when 'CM' then 900
    when 'D'  then 500
    when 'CD' then 400
    when 'C'  then 100
    when 'XC' then 90
    when 'L'  then 50
    when 'XL' then 40
    when 'X'  then 10
    when 'IX' then 9
    when 'V'  then 5
    when 'IV' then 4
    when 'I'  then 1
  end) as decimals
from t
connect by regexp_substr(str, '(CM|M|CD|D|XC|C|XL|L|IX|X|IV|V|I)', 1, level) is not null;

  DECIMALS
----------
      1984
```

Notice that the order of the search terms in the regex isn't the same as their equivalent decimal order; you need to match CM bfore M because of the subtractive notation.

If this is something you need to do a lot it's probably worth creating a deterministic function (which is true with the recursive CTE method too, of course). In which case you could switch to a PL/SQL loop to cut down on context switches:

```
create or replace function roman_to_decimal(p_roman varchar2)
return number deterministic is
  l_decimal number := 0;
begin
  for i in 1..regexp_count(p_roman, '(CM|M|CD|D|XC|C|XL|L|IX|X|IV|V|I)') loop
    l_decimal := l_decimal +
      case regexp_substr(p_roman, '(CM|M|CD|D|XC|C|XL|L|IX|X|IV|V|I)', 1, i)
        when 'M'  then 1000
        when 'CM' then 900
        when 'D'  then 500
        when 'CD' then 400
        when 'C'  then 100
        when 'XC' then 90
        when 'L'  then 50
        when 'XL' then 40
        when 'X'  then 10
        when 'IX' then 9
        when 'V'  then 5
        when 'IV' then 4
        when 'I'  then 1
      end;
  end loop;

  return l_decimal;
end;
/

select roman_to_decimal('DXV'), roman_to_decimal('MCMLXXXIV')
from dual;

ROMAN_TO_DECIMAL('DXV') ROMAN_TO_DECIMAL('MCMLXXXIV')
----------------------- -----------------------------
                    515                          1984
```

You can see and check all the conversions (1-3999, as that is the range supported by `to_char()`) with:

```
with t (orig, roman) as (
  select level, to_char(level, 'RN') from dual connect by level < 4000
)
select orig, roman, roman_to_decimal(roman)
from t;

      ORIG ROMAN           ROMAN_TO_DECIMAL(ROMAN)
---------- --------------- -----------------------
         1               I                       1
         2              II                       2
         3             III                       3
         4              IV                       4
         5               V                       5
         6              VI                       6
         7             VII                       7
         8            VIII                       8
         9              IX                       9
        10               X                      10
        11              XI                      11
...
      3994       MMMCMXCIV                    3994
      3995        MMMCMXCV                    3995
      3996       MMMCMXCVI                    3996
      3997      MMMCMXCVII                    3997
      3998     MMMCMXCVIII                    3998
      3999       MMMCMXCIX                    3999
```

Or just to verify they all convert back to their original values:

```
with t (original, roman) as (
  select level, to_char(level, 'RN') from dual connect by level < 4000
)
select original, roman, roman_to_decimal(roman)
from t
where roman_to_decimal(roman) != original;

no rows selected
```

This is very slightly slower than the recursive CTE equivalent for me, but might differ on other versiosn and platforms; and like I said, just for fun...

Comment: VERY nice! (a few more characters to fill the 15-chars limit; stupid restriction).

Answer (score 1):

This code is copied from the LiveSQL site (https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CESOH7H2D4O88XLW60330Q3L9.html). Author is Ms. Natalka Roshak.

> Convert Roman numeral to decimal format using recursive subquery. Pass in the Roman number to be converted by putting it in the ROMAN inline table in the With clause.

```
SQL> WITH
  2    roman ( numeral ) AS
  3    ( SELECT 'MCMLXXXVII' AS numeral FROM dual),
  4  romtodec (
  5    thisval,
  6    thisone,
  7    thisdec,
  8    lastdec,
  9    remaining,
 10    pos
 11  ) AS ( SELECT 0 AS thisval,
 12                CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR2(4000) ) AS thisone,
 13                0 AS thisdec,
 14                0 AS lastdec,
 15                roman.numeral AS remaining,
 16                length(roman.numeral) AS pos
 17         FROM roman
 18  UNION ALL
 19  SELECT
 20    CASE
 21      WHEN romtodec.thisdec >= romtodec.lastdec THEN romtodec.thisval + thisdec
 22      ELSE romtodec.thisval - thisdec
 23    END
 24  AS thisval,
 25    substr(romtodec.remaining,length(romtodec.remaining),1) AS thisone,
 26    CASE substr(romtodec.remaining,length(romtodec.remaining),1)
 27      WHEN 'M'   THEN 1000
 28      WHEN 'D'   THEN 500
 29      WHEN 'C'   THEN 100
 30      WHEN 'L'   THEN 50
 31      WHEN 'X'   THEN 10
 32      WHEN 'V'   THEN 5
 33      WHEN 'I'   THEN 1
 34      ELSE 0
 35    END
 36  AS thisdec,
 37    romtodec.thisdec AS lastdec,
 38    substr(romtodec.remaining,1,length(romtodec.remaining) - 1) AS remaining,
 39    length(romtodec.remaining) - 1 AS pos
 40  FROM romtodec
 41  WHERE pos >= 0
 42  ) SELECT thisval
 43    FROM romtodec
 44    WHERE pos IS NULL;

   THISVAL
----------
      1987

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below query for roman numerals to decimal numbers:

link - https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CESOH7H2D4O88XLW60330Q3L9.html

```
WITH Roman (Numeral) AS
(select 'DXV' as Numeral from dual),
RomToDec (ThisVal, ThisOne, ThisDec, LastDec, Remaining, Pos) AS
(SELECT 0 as ThisVal, cast(null as varchar2(4000)) as ThisOne, 
0 as ThisDec, 0 as LastDec,
Roman.Numeral as Remaining , length(Roman.Numeral) as Pos 
FROM Roman
UNION ALL
SELECT 
case 
  when RomToDec.ThisDec >= RomToDec.LastDec then RomToDec.ThisVal + ThisDec 
  else RomToDec.ThisVal-ThisDec
END as ThisVal, 
substr(RomToDec.Remaining,length(RomToDec.Remaining),1)  as ThisOne, 
case substr(RomToDec.Remaining,length(RomToDec.Remaining),1)  
  when 'M' then 1000
  when 'D' then 500
  when 'C' then 100
  when 'L' then 50
  when 'X' then 10
  when 'V' then 5
  when 'I' then 1
else 0 END as ThisDec,
RomToDec.ThisDec as LastDec,
substr(RomToDec.Remaining,1,length(RomToDec.Remaining)-1) as Remaining,
length(RomToDec.Remaining)-1 as Pos
from RomToDec                           
where Pos >= 0
)
select thisVal
from RomToDec 
where pos is null
```

Answer (score -2):

I think the [`TO_NUMBER`](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Database/Oracle_Number_Function/00__Oracle_TO_NUMBER.htm) function is what you're looking for.

something like: `... to_number('XIV', 'RN') ...`

Comment: I know the question wasn't originally in English but did you try anything?